# Are all topologies that are generated by uniform spaces $T_1$?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, uniform-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a [uniform space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) with uniformity $U$. We can make a topology as follows: for any $x\in X$ the set $\{u[x]:u\in U\}$ is a nhood base at $x$. Here $u[x] = \{y\in X: (x,y)\in u\}$.

Is the generated topology always $T_1$? I know that the generated topology is $T_2$ if and only if $\bigcap\limits_{u\in U} u = \{(x,x): x\in X\}$. Is it always $T_1$, or can we not say this?

Comment: $U = \{X\times X\}$ defines a uniform structure.

Comment: A uniform space is $T_0$ or $T_1$ or $T_2$ (these are all equivalent form uniform topologies) or even $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ iff it is "separated" which means that $\bigcap \{u: u \in U\} = \Delta_X = \{(x,x)  :x \in X\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the trivial uniform structure $\mathscr{U} = \{X\times X\}$, which induces the trivial topology. Unless $\operatorname{card} X \leqslant 1$, this is not a $T_1$ topology.

Apart from that, every topology induced by a uniform structure is a $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ topology (or completely regular, depending on the used nomenclature), and a $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$-space is Hausdorff if and only if it is $T_0$, so for topologies induced by uniform structures, $T_0,\, T_1,$ and $T_2$ are equivalent.

Comment: What about if the uniform spaces are complete?

Comment: Unless you make $T_2$ part of the definition of completeness, it doesn't change anything. Every filter on an indiscrete space converges, so the trivial uniformity is complete. The product of any nonempty complete uniform space with an indiscrete two-point space is a complete non-Hausdorff uniform space.

Comment: I see, I ask because I am trying to understand this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413373/each-x-alpha-is-homeomorphic-to-a-closed-set-in-pi-alpha-in-a-x-alpha